# Mysql Query to retrieve Values using if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```
select
      IFNULL(sum(invoice0_.INV_AMT),0)  as col_0_0_,IFNULL(sum(invoice1_.INV_AMT),0)  as col_0_0_
    from
        hrmanager.invoice invoice0_,
        hrmanager.invoice invoice1_
    where
         invoice0_.FROM_LEDGER=1
         **or** invoice1_.TO_LEDGER=1
        and (
            invoice0_.INV_DATE between '1900-12-20' and '2012-01-30'
        )
        and invoice0_.ACTIVE='Y'
        and invoice0_.COMP_ID=2
        and invoice1_.COMP_ID=2
        and invoice0_.INV_TYPE='CLIENT'
        and invoice1_.INV_TYPE='CLIENT';
```

Here i wish to select the sum of amount of all from_ledger =1 and next column should display the sum of amount of all to_ledger=1 but here gave and/or in the condition retrieve the same data,In Db here from ledger=1 then the result is 7000 and toledger=1 then it will 0 but the above query retrieve the two columns are same value like 0 or 7000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is a bit of a mess.  You are doing a query from the same table twice, but no JOIN condition which will result in a Cartesian result.  I THINK what you are looking for is that your table "Invoice" has two columns in it... "To_Ledger" and "From_Ledger", the "INV_AMT", and some other fields for criteria...  This should get you closer to your answer.

```
select
      sum( if( inv.From_Ledger = 1, inv.Inv_Amt, 0 )) as FromInvoiceAmounts,
      sum( if( inv.To_Ledger = 1, inv.Inv_Amt, 0 )) as ToInvoiceAmounts
   from
      hrmanager.invoice inv
   where
          1 in ( inv.From_Ledger, inv.To_Ledger )
      AND inv.inv_date between '1900-12-20' and '2012-01-30'
      and inv.Active = 'Y'
      and inv.Comp_ID = 2
      and inv.Inv_Type = 'CLIENT'
```